# Cocos2d-x - Programmatically change screen orientation

Tags: android, c++, ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Is it possible in Cocos2d-x to change the screen orientation while the game is running?

I've got a sequence / level in which the screen orientation should change and I'd like to have it also changed in the OS.

If I just o rotate the Scene the notification center slide-down and the button toolbar slide-up of iOS are on the wrong screen sides.

Answer (score 0):

This is platform specific and you would probably have to do it using the native java code on Android and objective-c on iOS.

Comment: True, but game engines are there to take away the platform-specific pain for us. That's why I was asking if cocos2d-x has something like this, or if somebody knows and extension / library that can do it.

Comment: There is nothing like this but cocos2d-x does make it simple to link native code to the c++ code. Your best bet to see if anyone has done it already would be a google search look for Github links